# Constructor injection versus attr_writer

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection

I need to write classes that have dependencies. I come from a .NET background, and in .NET we use constructor injection, primarily, to inject class dependencies into a class. I've read around and found most blogs (or at least the ones I have seen) have suggested using `attr_writer` (a la, property) injection for dependencies.

What I mean by dependencies:

```
class Engine
end

# A car requires an engine
class Car
  attr_writer :engine #Do we use attr_writer for dependencies, or..
  def initialize(engine) # Do we use constructor injection?
  end
end
```

What is the Ruby of injecting dependencies? `attr_writer` or constructor injection?

EDIT: To the previous person who edited my post, you made it very unclear as to what I was asking.

Comment: what do you mean dependencies? dependencies what of what?

Comment: Dependencies of classes. I.e, `class Car` has a dependency on  `class Engine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer constructor injection of dependencies as it prevents leakage of state of the objects.  If an object depends on attr_writer, anyone who uses that object needs to know what attributes he has to set in order to correctly initialise the state of the object.

With constructor parameters, you know that the object is correctly instantiated when the constructor returns.

To me, coming from a Java background:

```
engine = Engines::V8.new("vroom")
car = Car.new(engine)
```

is far cleaner than

```
car = Car.new
car.engine = Engines::V8.new("vroom")
```

because option 1 raises an explicit exception if I forget to provide a parameter, whereas option 2 just fails, unexpectedly, if I forget to give the car an engine.

my 2c.

edited to add: With a modern IDE like RubyMine, constructor-based injection also lends itself to quickly establishing the dependencies a class has, whereas attr_writer-based dependencies doesn't.